# Excel "If Then" formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I'm trying to write a formula which says "if sum of cell F24 to I24 plus sum of cell L6 to L9 sum up smaller than 50, show value in cell L9 in cell N9, and if not, subtract sum of cell F24 to I24 plus sum of cell L6 to L9 from 50 and show only positive value. For example, if sum of cell F24 to I24 plus sum of cell L6 to L9 sum up to 54 with sum of cell F24 to I24 plus sum of cell L6 to L8 sums up to 48, I want the formula to return 2 in cell N9.

The formula I now have is

```
=IF(SUM($F$24:$I$24)+SUM(L6:L9)<50,L9,((50-SUM($F$24:$I$24)-SUM(L6:L9))))
```

and returns negative value (-4) in cell N9.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If I'm reading your question right, you'd want to change ((50-SUM($F$24:$I$24)-SUM(L6:L9)))) to ((50-SUM($F$24:$I$24)-SUM(L6:L8)))). However, this only fixes your specific example. If you fiddled with the numbers a bit, you could easily break that formula.

Comment: Thank you Joe, the formula didn't work since, as you've indicated, fiddling with the number broke the formula. I'm trying to figure out a formula which I can use to track staff working hours and calculate overtime hrs once staff goes over certain number of hrs.

Comment: How about you post a few rows of data as an example and manually plug in the desired result. Then use simple words to describe the logic instead of posting a formula that does not work. Edit your question. Post some sample data for all scenarios in your question, not in a comment. Then post a comment to alert people here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to turn the negative value into a positive one. That can be done with the ABS() function.

```
=IF(SUM($F$24:$I$24)+SUM(L6:L9)<50,L9,ABS((50-SUM($F$24:$I$24)-SUM(L6:L9))))
```

Comment: Thank you, Teylyn. I should have been more clear in the question. What I'd like for the formula to return is, if sum of all the cells is 54 with sum of the cells excluding cell L9 is 48, I want a formula to return value 2 in cell L9.I don't want total returned value exceed 50.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to incorporate the `max' function, which is a handy way of making sure that your answer never goes below zero.

In your example, you'd want:

```
IF(SUM($F$24:$I$24)+SUM(L6:L9)<50,L9,MAX(0,(50-SUM($F$24:$I$24)-SUM(L6:L9)))
```

Thus, if 50-SUM($F$24:$I$24)-SUM(L6:L9) is negative, 0 will be returned.

That said, in your particular example, the third term has to always be zero or negative (because we only get there if SUM($F$24:$I$24)+SUM(L6:L9) is greater to or equal to 50) so you could just as easily write: `IF(SUM($F$24:$I$24)+SUM(L6:L9)<50,L9,0)`

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, I should have been more clear in the question. I'm trying to figure out a formula to track staff working hrs, and with the example, I'd like for the cell to return 2 so that it will be counted as regular hrs, totaling 50, and anything beyond 50 will calculate as overtime.

Comment: I've been away for a few weeks but see that your question still hasn't been answered.  I don't understand the example.  You have SUM($F$24:$I$24)+SUM(L6:L9) = 54, and

Comment: Oops, hit return and cant edit my comment for some reason.  Trying again:

Comment: This is killing me.  As I was saying, you have SUM($F$24:$I$24)+SUM(L6:L9) = 54, and SUM($F$24:$I$24)+SUM(L6:L8)=48.  What is the mathematical operation you are doing that results in 2?

Answer (score 0):

Your current formula says: If *X* (`F24:I24+L6:L9`) is less than 50, return L9. If *X* is more than 50, return 50 - *X*.
The second part "50-*X* if *X*>50" can only return a negative value.

In your description however, you omit L9 from the equation, and as stated by @Joe
the formula should end with `50-SUM($F$24:$I$24)-SUM(L6:L8)` Notice L**8**.

Also, you don't need multiple sums, so you can shorten it down to:

```
=IF(SUM($F$24:$I$24,L6:L9)<50,L9,50-SUM($F$24:$I$24,L6:L8))
```

However, if `F24:I24+L6:L8` is bigger than 50, it will still return a negative value.

Comment: Thank you Joe, I should have been more clear in the question. I'm trying to figure out a formula to track staff working hrs so that it will calculate regular hrs and overtime hrs once it exceeds certain number of hours.